# What's the best way to run multiple large PHP Files while logging progress without timing out?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cron

I've built a php script that generates JSON and since it sources alot of data it takes alot of time and can time out if I push it too far.

To prevent timing out I've setup cronjob's for all the php files that I've split it up too using loops and counters.

I have a list of php array of files such as:
`$array = array("01a.php","01b.php","01c.php","01d.php","01e.php","01f.php","01g.php","01h.php","01i.php","01j.php","02a.php","02b.php","02c.php","02d.php","02e.php","02f.php","02g.php","02h.php","02i.php","02j.php","03a.php","03b.php","03c.php","03d.php","03e.php","03f.php","03g.php","03h.php","03i.php","03j.php","04a.php","04b.php","04c.php","04d.php","04e.php","04f.php","04g.php","04h.php","04i.php","04j.php","05a.php","05b.php","05c.php","05d.php","05e.php","05f.php","05g.php","05h.php","05i.php","05j.php","06a.php","06b.php","06c.php","06d.php","06e.php","06f.php","06g.php","06h.php","06i.php","06j.php","07a.php","07b.php","07c.php","07d.php","07e.php","07f.php","07g.php","07h.php","07i.php","07j.php","08a.php","08b.php","08c.php","08d.php","08e.php","08f.php","08g.php","08h.php","08i.php","08j.php","09a.php","09b.php","09c.php","09d.php","09e.php","09f.php","09g.php","09h.php","09i.php","09j.php","10a.php","10b.php","10c.php","10d.php","10e.php","10f.php","10g.php","10h.php","10i.php","10j.php","11a.php","11b.php","11c.php","11d.php","11e.php","11f.php","11g.php","11h.php","11i.php","11j.php","12a.php","12b.php","12c.php","12d.php","12e.php","12f.php","12g.php","12h.php","12i.php","12j.php","13a.php","13b.php","13c.php","13d.php","13e.php","13f.php","13g.php","13h.php","13i.php","13j.php","14a.php","14b.php","14c.php","14d.php","14e.php","14f.php","14g.php","14h.php","14i.php","14j.php","15a.php","15b.php","15c.php","15d.php","15e.php","15f.php","15g.php","15h.php","15i.php","15j.php");`

Each of those files are setup to a cronjob time and sadly aren't perfectly accurate as they overlap sometimes as some files take more data than others.

What is the best way to run a array of php files one after another without timing out and perhaps tracking the progress through print output?

I've tried loops but the php execution time can usually be problematic as too much information is there and it crashes before it can finish importing.

Comment: CronJobs should not timeout. The PHP CLI does not pay attention to the `max_execution_time` parameter

Comment: They don't time out using Cronjobs it's just running all day 24/7 to get all the data and it seems there should be a faster way.

Comment: Then it might help to know a little more about what these jobs are doing and how they relate to the use of javascript as you tagged javascript

Comment: I only added the Javascript Tag in the event someone suggested something with Javascript for logging the task being processed.

Comment: _"I only added the Javascript Tag in the event someone suggested something with Javascript for logging the task being processed."_ ? What are you trying to achieve? What is "the task"?

Comment: I've updated the array in my original question to show how large the task is and why the cronjob is quite long. I'd like to create a php file that can be manually or scheduled to run the files one at at a time until the task is complete.

Currently I depend on the cronjob running and accomplishing, and have very little way to determine if it accomplished the task.

Comment: Out of interest, how long does it take (roughly) to complete a single cycle of all these scripts?

Comment: You still dont give us any idea what these scripts are doing! I cannot escape from the feeling that there must be a better way of achieving the result you require, but we still dont know what that requirement is?

Comment: Around 5 minutes per script

Comment: So that more than 12 hours to complete 1 set of script executions

Comment: The purpose of the script is very complex which is why I'm trying to stick to the basics of the array. Each php file within that array gathers information from an API then exports part of the data to external JSON Files. Those JSON files are then imported on a daily basis. The Task I'm trying to do is see if it's possible to make a PHP file that can be run manually or scheduled to process all these php files in order instead of timed in the cronjob.

Comment: Then why not create a single CRON that executed each script in turn. You get each script to return a good/bad status and check that between each job so you can abort the BATCH JOB if errors occur and send a warning email as well

Comment: But that sort of begs the question of why break the process into 150 sub processes unless some can be run in parallel. And I am back to the problem of not knowing enough about the total process to do anything other than make **guesses**

Comment: I think the process I am suggesting would traditionally be called a Multi Step Batch Job